# Force OpenTK to use a specific context

Tags: opengl, opentk

I am new to OpenTK and I saw that I can use the "core profile" like this

```
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
```

The problem is that my application starts with an OpenGL 4.0.0 context

```
 var s = GL.GetString(StringName.Version);
 Console.WriteLine(s);
```

How can I force OpenTK to start in OpenGL 4.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the code you are using to create your OpenGL context this is impossible to say. However, if you look at the [`OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsContext`](http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/class_open_t_k_1_1_graphics_1_1_graphics_context.html#aaeb217a1cc05317ad1798c941aeee99d) constructor, [you will notice](http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics/graphicscontext) that there are two parameters to control OpenGL Major/Minor version. If you request 4.4 it will do its best to get a 4.4 (or higher) context from your driver.

That said, do not expect very many shipping drivers to implement OpenGL 4.4 at the moment. NV is the only vendor that currently implements all of OpenGL 4.4. AMD tends to roll out support for new versions on an extension-by-extension basis, where as NV delivers it all at once in the form of a beta driver (though at this time, GL 4.4 is in NV's **release** drivers for qualifying hardware).